# Could not find mime-types-1.19 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

$rake db:migrate

error:

could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 18 column 3

how to solve this

i am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check .yml file.
give space before and after the ':'